# Stategy to draw a random sample of a huge joined table in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have two hive tables:

```
table_a (700e6 records, 800 partitions, 10 TB total size)
table_b (700e6 records, 800 partitions, 20 GB total size)
```

They are partitioned by the same column ( `table_b` contains computed metadata for `table_a`).

I want to join these table and take a random sample (lets say 1E-5) using `dataFrame.sample(false,1E-5)`

Should I

a) join tables and then take random sample?

b) draw random sample from `table_a` or `table_b` and then join?

c) draw random sample from `table_b`, then broadcast this dataframe (`sc.boradcast(dataframe)` and then join with `table_a`?

I tried all 3 options, all take "forever". is there a more intelligent way to do this?